# Is there a way to make sure formatted string is always in quotations?

Tags: python, powershell

I am working on a new tool to help automate some tedious processes.
it involves ExchangeOnlineManagement, Python, and Powershell.

I have input variables that I am feeding into Powershell commands via Formatted string.

An example that works:

```
Email = input("Please provide your domain email address ")

sp.run(f"Connect-IPPSSession -UserPrincipalName {Email}", shell=True)
```

This works with no problem.

However, when I run:

```
Search_Name = input("What is the name of the Content Search? ")

sp.run(f'Get-ComplianceSearchAction {Search_Name}', shell=True)
```

I get the following:

```
+ Get-ComplianceSearchAction @chanroodee.com_purge
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@chanroodee' can be used only as an argument to a command.    
To reference variables in an expression use '$chanroodee'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

The original syntax for the command (That works on my machine currently) is

```
Get-ComplianceSearchAction "@chanroodee.com_purge"
```

I am assuming that because there are no quotes around the Search_Name var, it is not processing it as an argument. So my goal I guess is to enable quotes to be around every string that passes through the Search_Name input. so that it can be processed as an argument rather than a random string.

Comment: `f'Get-ComplianceSearchAction "{Search_Name}"'`!? You would then only need to make sure there is no `"` inside the `Search_Name` itself.

Comment: Or use `!r` for "repr" formatting if _only_ strings should be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***fully robust* solution** that guarantees that whatever string value you pass to PowerShell is used *verbatim* requires:

- using embedded `'...'` quoting
- which in turn requires that any `'` characters contained in the value be escaped as `''`:

```
Search_Name = input("What is the name of the Content Search? ")
Search_Name_Escaped = Search_Name.replace("'", "''")
sp.run(f'Get-ComplianceSearchAction \'{Search_Name_Escaped}\'', shell=True)
```

<sup>Note that it is tempting to attempt putting the expression `Search_Name.replace("'", "''")` directly inside `{...}` in the -f-string, but that would require `\`-escaping the `'` chars, whereas use of `\` isn't supported inside `{...}`.</sup>

---

A ***simpler* solution** is possible **if you can assume that your string values never contain `` ` `` or `$` characters** (which would be subject to string interpolation by PowerShell inside `"..."`), **using `!r`**, as suggested by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), which calls the string's `__repr__()` method in order to automatically return a *quoted* representation of the value - which uses embedded `'...'` quoting by default, but switches to embedded `"..."` quoting if the string itself contains `'` (and not also `"`):

```
Search_Name = input("What is the name of the Content Search? ")
sp.run(f'Get-ComplianceSearchAction {Search_Name!r}', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using your second solution. f'Get-ComplianceSearchAction "{Search_Name}"' didn't seem to work correctly for me. But !r did.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TheSecAtlas; `!r` results in embedded `'...'` quoting (unless the value itself contains `'` and not also `"`). It's curious that the `"..."` solution doesn't work, however.

Answer (score 1):

Something like: `f'Get-ComplianceSearchAction "{Search_Name}"'`?

Comment: That will _typically_ work, and is probably enough in this case, but it's worth noting that this approach isn't fully robust:  it will break if  the value of `Search_Name` contains `"` characters itself (e.g., `Search_Name = '3" of snow'`)